# Converting SQL Server database to local C# database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

I have created program that uses SQL Server database to store data. After a while (and lots of stored data) I have realized I don't need database on the server, local database running without server could do the job.

Now I need some advice how to export, convert or whatever, SQL Server database to local (sdf) database? I'm using VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008, I also have SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What's your primary motivation for moving away from SQL Server? Licensing? Reduced installation requirement? Something else?

Comment: Well that software is "from me for me" and i don't need MSSQL server running every time i start windows, i just don't want to worry about it if i can use compact DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [SQL Server to SQL Server Compact Edition Copy Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlCompactCoptUtility.aspx) available on CodeProject in C# source code:

[image]

Should do just what you need: copy data from SQL Server to a SQL Server Compact Edition .sdf file.

Comment: Can it work with MSSQL 2008? On screenshot you provided, latest supported version is 2005

Comment: @guest86: don't know - you can find [the latest version here](http://www.johnnycantcode.com/page/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database-Copy.aspx) - ask the author!

Comment: Ok, you gave me a direct answer so i'll try your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Export database tool? If you are using MS Windows OS then you can access is through the JET interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use my Export2sqlce.exe command line utility: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html